# Kendo Grid DropdownList And Insert template Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, grid

I have been struggling with this issue and hit a roadblock. I have a kendo grid that has a dropdownlist.

**Problem**

1. When i edit a record by selecting a value in the DropdownList, the
   field is not updated.
2. When i select the Add Command from the toolbar, a different
   template tries to render and raises the error "***Uncaught ReferenceError:
   ParentMenu is not defined"*** in Chrome debugs. So nothing happens consequently.
3. When i comment out *"values: parentRef"* from the kendogrid columns definition all commands[Add,Edit] display properly

I have demonstrated the error i am experiencing here **http://jsfiddle.net/BlowMan/5tNQy/**

**JS Code**

```
$(function () {
var mbModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "MenuId",
    fields: {
        "MenuId": {
            type: "number"
        },
            "DisplayText": {
            type: "string"
        },
            "MenuOrder": {
            type: "number"
        },
            "MenuStatus": {
            type: "boolean"
        },
            "HasKids": {
            type: "boolean"
        },
            "ParentMenu": {
            type: "number",
            defaultValue: 1
        }
    }
});

var mbDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        "MenuId": 1,
        "DisplayText": "Home",
        "MenuOrder": 0,
        "MenuStatus": true,
        "HasKids": false,
        "ParentMenu": null
    }, {
        "MenuId": 2,
        "DisplayText": "Finance",
        "MenuOrder": 1,
        "MenuStatus": true,
        "HasKids": false,
        "ParentMenu": null
    }]

});
var parentRef = [{
    "value": 1,
    "text": "Finance"
}, {
    "value": 2,
    "text": "Corp. Services"
}];
$("#menuBuilder1").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "MenuId",
        title: "Menu",
        editable: true
    }, {
        field: "DisplayText",
        title: "Name",
        editable: true
    }, {
        field: "MenuOrder",
        title: "Order",
        editable: true
    }, {
        field: "MenuStatus",
        title: "MenuStatus",
        editable: true
    }, {
        field: "HasKids",
        title: "Depends",
        editable: true
    }, {
        field: "ParentMenu",
        title: "ParentMenu",
        values: parentRef
    }, {
        title: "Action",
        command: ["edit"]
    }],
    toolbar: ["create"],
    editable: "popup",
    schema: {
        model: mbModel
    }
});

var mbObject = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    data: mbDataSource,
    //parentRef:[]
});

kendo.bind($("#menuBuilder1"), mbObject);
mbDataSource.bind("change", function (e) {

});
var grid = $("#menuBuilder1").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("save", function (e) {
    var that = this;
    that.refresh();
});

grid.bind("edit", function (e) {

});

$.ajax({
    url: "/MenuBuilder/GetMenuWithKids",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (ret) {
        mbObject.set("parentRef", ret);
    }
});
```

});

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="menuBuilder1" data-bind="source:data"></div>
```

Am in a tight corner and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: When you give initial value 1 or 2 as ParentMenu in mbDataSource, update works correctly. You can give 0  for initial null value. But it  doesn't works correctly(For select finance you have to select corp. services first, then select finance otherwise grid doesn't notice value changed)

Comment: I couldn't find anything about other problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the workaround. Did you take a look at Problem #2?

Comment: I 've looked, chrome debugger gives MenuId is not defined. You said you used a different template for create but I could't see where is the template.

Comment: The error i reported in prblm#2 was whiles running from Visual Studio and debugging in chrome. I see it has changed to MenuId in jsfiddle. However,the "Add New" pop-up fails to appear.Please assist

Comment: where is the create template ? Or are you using standart create pop up?

Comment: Yes, i am using the standard. i have not created any custom template. The jsfiddle is all i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MustafaP solved Problem 1.

For problem 2, 
I realised that i had placed the schema definition at the wrong place within the kendoGrid. I placed it at the bottom after the toolbar.
It should rather be placed just after the kendoGrid brackets

```
$("#menuBuilder1").kendoGrid({
    schema: {
        model: mbModel
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "MenuId",
        title: "Menu",
        editable: true
```